# Faster image upload on mobile

Tags: image

So, for my wordpress mobile site, there is a button to upload an image (either from camera or phone gallery).

However since the size of mobile images are well over 3 MB, it takes too long to upload them.

Is there a way to reduce the image size before the upload even happens? or to speed up the uploading process.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have some solutions:

1. Compress image before send; open image in your graphic editor and save as JPEG or PNG with lower quality; file will be <3MB
2. Upgrade your home internet - upload parameter is important here
3. Upgrade your server plan - maybe you can have better network connection.

You can't make it faster by changing the code or something.

Comment: Well, do you think image size can be reduce on the client side (on their mobile phone)?  The image will be uploaded by the user on the client side (mobile) and none of the options are ideal as it is hard to control those.

Comment: Yes, best way is use application to resize on smartphone. You can use File API (read on MDN), load it to canvas and rescale.